# Double has_many relation with an extra join model in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In Ruby on Rails I have the following models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Has a field called runs_visibility that is 0 if the runs are publicly visible
  has_many :runs
end

class Tour < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :runs
end

class Run < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :photos, as: :photo_parent

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :tour
end

class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :photo_parent, polymorphic: true
end
```

If i have an instance of Tour, what is the best way to access all the photos belonging to runs that belong to the tour where the users(belonging to the runs) have the runs_visibility field set to 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First add a run relation to the Photo class like this

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :photo_parent, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :run, -> { where(photos:{photo_parent_type: 'Run'}) },
    foreign_key: 'photo_parent_id'
end
```

Then it is possible to add a has_many through relation that will join with the users table and filter as described in the question.

```
class Tour < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :runs
  has_many :public_runs_photos,
       -> { joins(run: :user).where(users: { runs_visibility: 0 } ) },
       through: :runs,
       source: :photos
end
```

So to get the public photos for the first tour:

```
Tour.first.public_runs_photos
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
class Tour < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :runs
  has_many :hidden_photos, -> { joins(run: :user).where(run: { user: { runs_visibility: 0 }}) }, through: :runs, source: :photos
end

tour = Tour.find(1)
tour.hidden_photos
```

It takes `photos` association through `runs` association on `Tour`, joins a `User` to which run belongs and filters photos based on `users.runs_visibility` column.

I didn't run this code since I don't have your setup, but I hope it should work.

Comment: Sadly that gives: ActiveRecord::ConfigurationError: Association named 'user' was not found on Photo; perhaps you misspelled it?

Comment: With the update, the new error message is: NameError: uninitialized constant Photo::PhotoParent

Comment: *sigh* it's really hard to debug this without live rails console. Please, try one more time.

Comment: It's kind of tricky with the console to, sorry, no luck: ActiveRecord::ConfigurationError: Association named 'run' was not found on Photo; perhaps you misspelled it?